# How to generate a link and navigate to app without building website

Tags: android

I am trying to build an android application . There is an option "share" to share the current product details in "WhatsApp".There is no website for this app.In that case which link should I share so that particular product details activity in my app should be opened when someone clicks.

pls see the modified code

```
<activity
            android:name="com.bodaty.samyata.samyata4.profiles.Profile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.bodaty.samyata.samyata4.customer_service.Contacts"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.bodaty.samyata.samyata4.barcode.Barcode"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.bodaty.samyata.samyata4.login_pages.EmailVerification"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.bodaty.samyata.samyata4.product_search.Details"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name ="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name ="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name ="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:host="www.samyata.com"
                    android:scheme="samyata"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.bodaty.samyata.samyata4.product_search.VoiceRecognitionActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
```

java code:

```
  //.....for network.....//
    NetworkReceiver networkReceiver;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
        setTitle("Product_Details");
        if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }


        Intent i1 = getIntent();
        Uri data = i1.getData();
        if(data != null){
            Log.e("data", String.valueOf(data));
        }else{
            Log.e("data123", String.valueOf(data));
        }

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user_id = mAuth.getUid();

        listView = findViewById(R.id.list);
        ratingBar1 = findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
        img = findViewById(R.id.img);
        ls_data=new ArrayList<>();

        // for network...//
        linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
        networkReceiver = new NetworkReceiver();
```

Logcat

```
 Increasing code cache capacity to 1024KB
08-01 07:25:33.316 25408-25413/com.bodaty.samyata.samyata4 I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=497KB, data=314KB
08-01 07:25:33.319 25408-25413/com.bodaty.samyata.samyata4 I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=484KB, data=261KB
08-01 07:25:34.420 25408-25408/com.bodaty.samyata.samyata4 I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 9352 bytes, containing 1 windows, 44 views
08-01 07:25:34.559 25408-25413/com.bodaty.samyata.samyata4 I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=490KB, data=277KB
08-01 07:25:34.565 25408-25413/com.bodaty.samyata.samyata4 I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=490KB, data=277KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 2MB
08-01 07:25:42.710 25408-25408/com.bodaty.samyata.samyata4 E/data123: null
```

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links/

Answer (score 0):

Without a website, this relies on the precondition that your app is preinstalled on user device.

Let's say your app name is MyApp the domain you choose to associate with your app is www.myapp.com

Now, whenever user clicks on a link "https://www.myapp.com/productA", detail page of productA should open in DetailActivity.class

To achieve this, you have to add an intent filter in your manifest against DetailActivity.class declaraion:

```
 <activity
    android:name=".DetailActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:host="www.myapp.com"
            android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

in your activity, you can get the url which landed you to that screen as follows:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     Intent intent = getIntent();
     Uri data = intent.getData(); // data= https://www.myapp.com/productA
     String productId = data.getLastPathSegment() // "productA"
}
```

Now using this data, you can show details for productA.

You can define your landing url using any of the below filters:

```
<data android:scheme="string"
      android:host="string"
      android:port="string"
      android:path="string"
      android:pathPattern="string"
      android:pathPrefix="string"
      android:mimeType="string" />
```

for more info, refer to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element

NOTE: when user clicks on the link, he will be shown a dialogue to choose between the browser and your app. This assumes he selects your app.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to implement this now, but  android:host="www.myapp.com" is fine but how append host with product id

Comment: you don't need to. all urls with this host will land to your activity

Comment: is the above code sufficient to generate this  url// data= https://www.myapp.com/productA.? no need of product A. then how will it redirect to that particular product details activity. can you pls tell

Comment: yes it is sufficient. To get productA, refer to activity onCreate code in my ans

Comment: hi sir , I have implemented but its showing null value in data

Comment: <data android:host="www.samyata.com"
                    android:scheme="samyata"/>
why sheme as samatya? what is the url you are sharing

Comment: url should be like  samyata/www.samyata.com/productid when you click on this link it should redirect to that particular activity

Comment: set scheme as "http"

Comment: first I have  used http its showing null value only, later I have changed to samyata

Comment: change it back to http and click on this link on your device:  http://www.samyata.com

Comment: I have a doubt ... I have placed intent- filter in manifest file , later I have placed intent in details .java and printed that in logical . its showing null. is the process correct